# Card reader draining battery in Dell laptop?

Tags: 16.04, dell, laptop, power-management, battery

I just bought a brand new Dell laptop and installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it. The battery started acting strange, i.e.: draining rapidly, and at times the system will shut down (when unplugged) even if there is still a lot of battery left.

The best battery time I get is about 1h30m just with Google Chrome open, which is not good.

I installed `powertop` and this is what I see:

[image]

The USB2.0-CRW device (the card reader) is *constantly* consuming over 12 W. Even when there is **no card inserted**.

This can't be right. Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: What's the device ID of the card reader? You can find it in the output of `lsusb`.

Comment: … and please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814)).